# How to obtain the microfiche appendix of a patent (containing the relevant source code)?

Tags: microfiche, appendix, us6544098

This [patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/US6544098) claims to have the source code attached in a microfiche appendix:

> MICROFICHE APPENDIX
>
> This application includes, pursuant to 37 C.F.R. §§1.77(c)(2), 1.96(b), a microfiche appendix consisting of four (4) sheets of microfiche containing 297 frames of a program listing embodying the present invention.

Is this appendix publicly available?

Can it be obtained for personal research purposes?

*EDIT: corrected the patent link.*

Comment: If anyone came here looking for that particular patent, I'd like to note that I've been able to obtain the source code thanks to Sean Riddle (seanriddle.com). It's now on archive.org: https://archive.org/details/furby-source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively the microfiche should be part of the publication and therefore accessible. The [relevant MPEP section](https://mpep.uspto.gov/RDMS/MPEP/E8r8#/E8r8/d0e50993.html) calls the cd (successor of the microfiche) part of the publication and disclosure. I conclude that access must be possible, however this section doesn't help.

The [MPEP section on availability to the public of patent (applications)](https://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s103.html) clearly supports this:

It does not explicitly mention cds/microfiches, however as they are part of the publication upon paying the relevant fee I see no reason why one would not obtain a copy.

Furthermore, [the fee listing for copies of patent documents](https://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/mpep-9020-appx-r.html#d0e315991) in section 1.19 (b) (1) (ii) provides the fee for patent documents submitted on physical electronic storage devices.

Even if that section wouldn't apply, below is noted that a fee will be set by the director if non applies.

Conclusion: it's possible, but you'll probably have to pay for it.

Comment: off-topic: hey, I'm really sorry for letting the bounty expire...

Comment: @Mark no problem, glad to help. If you try obtaining the microfiche please add an answer telling us how it went afterwards

Comment: By the way, what is the means of requesting such patent information (e.g. whom should I contact)?

Comment: @Mark the USPTO (I don't know whom exactly tbh). But you can try calling them and asking or send a letter/fax with the request.